# Esse trecho de código é jQuery? E o que ele faz?

Tags: javascript, jquery

O trecho de código abaixo:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     $('#menu #<? echo $idMenuAtivo; ?>').addClass('active');
 </script>
```

É escrito em jQuery ou JavaScript? E o que ele faz?

Comment: Na verdade esse código é uma mistura de jQuery com PHP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim, a grande parte desse código é jQuery, mas ele também possui PHP, no estilo *tudo junto e misturado*. O que pode ser *novidade* é que este é um código misturado com PHP.

### Explicação do código

Veja que possui a tag `<script>` - indicando que iniciam códigos JavaScript - e dentro da mesma possui abertura da tag PHP (usando [*short open tags*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)) `<?` - indicando que iniciam códigos PHP.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $('#menu #<? echo $idMenuAtivo; ?>').addClass('active');
</script>
```

Alguns pontos fáceis de identificação do jQuery, além da sua sintaxe:

- O cifrão - `$`:

  > - **Nota**: A biblioteca jQuery expõe seus métodos e propriedades através de duas propriedades do objeto de janela chamado **jQuery** e **$**. $ É simplesmente um *alias* para jQuery e muitas vezes é empregado porque é mais curto e rápido para escrever. <sup>[1](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)</sup>
- Método `.addClass()`:

  > - .addClass( nomeClasse ) - Adiciona a (s) classe (s) especificada (s) a cada elemento no conjunto de elementos correspondentes. <sup>[1](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)</sup>

No caso desse código, quando for executado a linha, vai adicionar a classe *active* ao elemento com `id` igual ao da variável `$activeMenu`.

Mais informações você pode encontrar no site do [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)<sup>en</sup>.

---

### Algumas observações

Como dito nos comentários, e também muito importante ressaltar:

> Essa integração PHP/JS só funciona quando o código JavaScript é colocado junto à página PHP. Utilizar esta sintaxe em um arquivo JavaScript não funcionará, pois o trecho em PHP não será interpretado.

E também para conseguir rodar o arquivo você deve ter um arquivo jquery.js, o qual você pode [baixar no site do próprio jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/), ou pode utilizar um [CDN](http://code.jquery.com/), mais ou menos dessa maneira:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

> Os atributos de *integrity* e *crossorigin* são usados para verificação de integridade de sub-recursos (SRI). Isso permite que os navegadores garantam que os recursos hospedados em servidores de terceiros não tenham sido adulterados. O uso de SRI é recomendado como uma **prática recomendada**, sempre que as bibliotecas são carregadas a partir de uma fonte de terceiros.

Leia mais em  [SRI Hash Generator](https://www.srihash.org/).

Comment: Vale lembrar que essa integração PHP/JS só funciona quando o código JavaScript é colocado junto à página PHP. Utilizar esta sintaxe em um arquivo JavaScript não funcionará, pois o trecho em PHP não será analisado.

Comment: Muito bem lembrado @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss A menos que o webserver seja explicitamente configurado para processar arquivos JS com o PHP – o que é raro, e eu não recomendaria. Só pra registrar.